# SQL Server : Calculate STArea from Geometry value

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

I know [how to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/starea-geometry-data-type) calculate STArea from text data , e.g.

```
DECLARE @g geometry;  
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0),(2 2, 2 1, 1 1, 1 2, 2 2))', 0);  
SELECT @g.STArea();
```

I have imported entries into a geom column, from a shape file.

How do I calculate STArea from Geom column?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the same function call as what you already wrote, `STArea()`. In your example you are not calculating the area of a text variable, you are first converting your text to a geometry and then calculating it's area (your variable is type `GEOMETRY`!).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GeometricData') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #GeometricData

CREATE TABLE #GeometricData (GeometricColumn GEOMETRY)

INSERT INTO #GeometricData (
    GeometricColumn)
SELECT
    GeometricColumn = geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 3 0, 3 3, 0 3, 0 0),(2 2, 2 1, 1 1, 1 2, 2 2))', 0)

SELECT
    G.GeometricColumn,
    Area = G.GeometricColumn.STArea()
FROM
    #GeometricData AS G
```

If you mean how to group geometry figures, then you need to aggregate them using `Geometry::UnionAggregate` before calling `STArea()`.

```
SELECT
    Area = Geometry::UnionAggregate(G.GeometricColumn).STArea()
FROM
    #GeometricData AS G
```

You can also group by column values.

```
SELECT
    G.GroupingValue,
    Area = Geometry::UnionAggregate(G.GeometricColumn).STArea()
FROM
    #GeometricData AS G
GROUP BY
    G.GroupingValue
```